# How to restrict uploading exe file in salesforce

Tags: community, force.com, sales-cloud

How to restrict exe file upload in salesforce using configuration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can control the download behaviour of the files using configuration(Point & Click). However as far as i know we do not have any standard declarative way in which you can control the file to be uploaded.

Please see below link: 
https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=admin_files_type_security.htm&siteLang=en_US

The above link does state that certain types of files can be rstricted from getting uploaded. However it is very limited:

> To prevent users from uploading files that may pose a security risk, select **Don't allow HTML uploads as attachments or document records**.
>   This setting blocks upload of these MIME file types: **.html, .htt, .mht, .svg, .swf, .thtml, and .xhtml.**

To achieve your requirement, you would need to write a trigger on attachments object. This will be on before insert event and you would need to check the file name with its extension. Something like below:

```
List<Attachment> lstAttachementTobeRestricted = new List<Attachment>();

for(Attachment at: trigger.New){

    String fileName =  at.Name;
    List<String> fileNameithExtension = fileName.split('\\.');
    fileExtension = fileNameithExtension[fileNameithExtension.size() - 1];

    if(fileExtension == 'exe'){
        lstAttachementTobeRestricted[at];
    }

}

for(Attachment att : lstAttachementTobeRestricted){
    att.addError('EXE not allowed');
}
```

Please note instead of comparing the fileextension in code, a better way would be to store those extensions in custom setting and then refer the custom setting in code. This way, you could add more extension types in the future.

Also note that the option of writing a trigger is limited to only Attachments object. If you wish to restrict for Documents object, you cannot write a trigger on Document object.

**UPDATE:**

In case you are using feeds, you would need to write a trigger on [FeedItem object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) and use **ContentFileName** field. The logic would remain the same as above. Below is a sample code i tried for single record. You would have to bulkify your code if needed. Also note the trigger on feed item is a after insert.

```
trigger CheckFileExtensionForFeedAttachment on FeedItem (**after insert**{
if(trigger.new[0].hasContent){`     
        system.debug('=========='+trigger.new[0].ContentFileName);
        List<String> lststr = trigger.new[0].ContentFileName.split('\\.');
        String fileExt = lststr[lststr.size() - 1];
        if(fileExt.equalsIgnoreCase('exe')){
            trigger.new[0].addError('EXE not allowed');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response.
I have written trigger on Attachment but when i upload file from case feed, Trigger didn't even execute. 
Didn't Find any log/

Comment: Updated the answer when using feeds.

Comment: i have fixed it but thank you so much for response

Answer (score 0):

Create a validation rule on ContentVersion that compares the FileType to a list of file extension types that match the types you want to prevent.